# Android context from tab activity

Tags: android, android-activity, tabs, helper, android-context

I have a helper class that I need context so I can access the `SharedPrefences`. Other posts recommend passing in the application context on instantiation of the helper class. So I made that change, it works very well except within a tab activity. The tab activity need to call a webservice to determine what data to display. The helper class makes the webservice call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get a null pointer you might be calling the function too early. In what function are you calling it?

Comment: good suggestion. I moved the instantiation into the onCreate method and it works. Much appreciated idea.

Answer (score 2):

You can call getContext() from any activity. If the helper class is defined as a subclass of the activity, it can call it directly. Otherwise, passing the context through instantiation would be my second choice. I agree, it's not pretty passing contexts everywhere. There are probably some complicated OOP patterns you could use to avoid this, but I can't see it being an advantage overall.

Comment: Just pass the context in through the constructor of non activity classes and that will work, sometimes cruft is required.

Comment: I have tried this way of doing it: ApiInterface apiinterface = new ApiInterface(this.getApplicationContext());
However I get a null pointer exception.